# Add the "closed" appendage to the hover tooltip on the profile page

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, tooltips, question-summary

When looking at the profile page for a user, the summaries for questions and answers have a maximum length which, when exceeded, turns into an ellipsis. When a question gets closed, the normal `[closed]` text is appended to the end of the title, like so:

[image: I know this one is closed.]

However, the tooltip for hovering doesn't contain that same `[closed]` text. So what? Well, it becomes more annoying for questions which *do* get cut off, because the text isn't there, and the tooltip doesn't contain it either.

[image: I don't know this one is closed.]

The question above is closed. However, since the end is ellipsed and the tooltip doesn't have the `[closed]` text to indicate this, I wouldn't know that unless I actually clicked through to the question itself. Even then, if it's an answer I may not be scrolled by default to a position where I'd even be able to tell if the question is closed or not.

Can we append the `[closed]` text (and other appended texts) to the hover tooltip in these summary boxes? It's natural behavior to hover over text to get the full title of something when the end is ellipsed to indicate more follows. It's not as helpful when that text doesn't contain all the information you'd *normally* expect to find there.

Comment: Good suggestion, I would go even further and suggest changing the background of closed questions - deleted posts have pale red background in the profile (e.g. in the favorites tab) maybe closed posts can have pale yellow or something like that to clearly indicate they are closed without even having to read the title.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Nice idea! I didn't think of that.

Comment: Thanks, I think it was suggested before though (as part of something else, but still) and pretty much ignored. Might be worth looking for it and bumping?